# Confusion about limit of integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Q. $$\iint_R y-2x \ dx dy$$ where $R=R[1,2; 3,6]$

Is this integration supposed to be

$$\int_2^6 \int_1^3 y-2x \ dx dy$$ or $$\int_3^6 \int_1^2 y-2x \ dx dy$$?

Comment: I would guess the second one. But it's not a notation I have seen before.

Comment: You would have to find the notation $R[1,2;3,6]$ explained earlier in  that same book.